# django filters open_hours close_hours SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I was trying to make filter method to check if my Place(model is below) is open right now. I defined fields open_hours and close_hours. Algorithm looks pretty well for me(First conditions applies to 21:00-23:00 hour and second 21:00-01:00) but Since I'm kind a new in Q and F objects I get syntaxError.

line 81
    Q(open_hours__lt = current_time) & Q(close_hours__gt = current_time))
    ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

```
class Place(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
lat = models.FloatField()
lng = models.FloatField()
address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
district = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DISTRICTS)
link = models.URLField(help_text="www.websiteurl.pl")
open_hours = models.TimeField()
close_hours = models.TimeField()
week_day = MultiSelectField(choices=DAYS)
additionalInfo = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name




def hasToBeOpenedRightNowFilter(self, queryset, name, value):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()                                               
    current_day = now.strftime("%A")                                        #current_day
    current_time = now.time()                                               #current_time

    queryset_day = queryset.filter(week_day__contains = current_day)        #queryset filtered after day
    query_time_1 = queryset.filter(open_hours__lt = F('close_hours'),       #queryset filtered after first condition
    Q(open_hours__lt = current_time) & Q(close_hours__gt = current_time))       
    query_time_2 = queryset.filter(open_hours__gt = F('close_hours'),       #queryset filtered after second condition
    Q(open_hours__lt = current_time) | Q(close_hours__gt = current_time))
    queryset_time = query_time_1 | query_time_2                             #merge two querysets with time conditions
    queryset_true = queryset_time & queryset_day                            #merge queryset with filter after day
    if not value:
        queryset = queryset.exclude(id__in=queryset_true.values('id'))
        return queryset
    return queryset_true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the Q objects first in the `.filter`

```
query_time_1 = queryset.filter(Q(open_hours__lt = current_time) & Q(close_hours__gt = current_time), open_hours__lt = F('close_hours'))
```

Comment: Oh, that would make sense. Thank you :))))